# Mongoid has_many with metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I have an `Order` model, that contains many `products`. I want to be able to keep track of which products are shipped, and which aren't, so I would like to keep track of some metadata that goes along with each relation. If this was a `has_one` relation, then it would be simple, just insert a few more fields.

***How can I accomplish this with a `has_many` relation between an `Order` model and a `Product` model cleanly using Mongoid?***

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself my using another model `OrderProduct` as a proxy between the two. The implementation of the state was done using the `state_machine` gem. I ended up wrapping a lot of the calls to the product's state machine in the Order model. This allows me to call things like `.product_state(product)` or `can_cancel_product?(product)` on the order instance.

**Order**

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :state, type: String

  embeds_many :order_products

  state_machine initial: :open do
    ...
  end

  def products
    order_products.map do |op|
      op.product
    end.freeze
  end

  def add_product(product)
     OrderProduct.create({_product: product._id, order: self})
  end

  def remove_product(product)
    order_products.delete find_order_product(p)
  end

  #wrapper for product events
  OrderProduct.new.state_paths.events.each do |event|
    define_method "#{event}_product" do |product|
      find_order_product(product).send(event)
    end
    define_method "can_#{event}_product?" do |product|
      find_order_product(product).send("can_#{event}?")
    end
  end

  #wrapper for product states
  OrderProduct.state_machine.states.map(&:name).each do |state|
    define_method "product_#{state}?" do |product|
      find_order_product(product).send("#{state}?")
    end
  end

  #wrapper for product current state
  def product_state(product)
    find_order_product(product).state
  end

  private
    def find_order_product(p)
      order_products.at(order_products.index do |op|
        op.product == p
      end)
    end

end
```

**OrderProduct**

```
class OrderProduct

  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :order
  field :_product, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId

  state_machine initial: :open do
    ....
  end

  def product
    Product.find(_product)
  end
  def product=(product)
    _product = (product._id)
  end

end
```